# Repeated elements of bijections of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics

Let $f: \mathbb{Z}_{2n} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_{2n}$ be a bijective map, where $n \geq 2$. Is it true that the set $\{f(t)-t: t \in \mathbb{Z}_{2n}\}$ contains at least two repeated elements?

Comment: So we are seeing $(f(t)-t)$ mod(2n) right?

Comment: @Riju: yeah, right, mod 2n.

Comment: Consider the sum $\sum_t(f(t)-t)$ as the previously deleted answer says.

Answer (score 2):

The conjecture is true.  Consider $\sum_{t\in\mathbb{Z}_{2n}}(f(t)-t)$.  If all these are distinct then they must be equivalent to set $\mathbb{Z}_{2n}$ in some order, when considered modulo $2n$.  So $$0 = \sum_{t\in\mathbb{Z}_{2n}}(f(t)-t) \equiv \sum_{t\in\mathbb{Z}_{2n}}t = n(2n+1) \equiv n \pmod{2n},$$ a contradiction. Q.E.D.!

Comment: {3,1,-1,-3} *has* two repeated elements mod 4.

Comment: Is $f(t) - t$ automatically working modulo $2n$? I wasn't sure, but if it is then just disregard the first sentence -- the rest is still true.

Comment: I don't understand your comment: you proved that at least one element is repeated, which is correct. Your counterexample doesn't seem to work imho

Comment: To be explicit, in your example $\{f(t)-t\}\equiv \{1,1,3,3\}\bmod 4$.

Comment: If I just gave you the set {3, 1, -1, -3} there would be no two repeated elements.  If I said "no two repeated elements modulo 4" that is a different story... right?

Comment: Well, everything here is in $\mathbf{Z}_{2n}$, otherwise also the proof that there is at least one repeated element doesn't work. If you were correct, then it would mean that you just provided a counterexample to what you proved below.

Comment: We're both saying the same thing -- I was just clarifying the question. I didn't realize the subtraction operated modulo 2n. I proved the same thing that you did, which was that the conjecture is true mod 2n

Comment: Fractal yes, I am thinking now that maybe the OP was just asking the simpler question if it is just a bijection mod 2n. Anyway, this is a well-known exercise, and it can be proved that this is not bijection (mod n) iff n is even. Indeed, if n is odd, it is enough to take $f(t)=-t$ for all $t\in \mathbf{Z}_n$.

Answer (score 2):

Let us suppose for the sake of contradiction that $\{\sigma(t)+\sigma^\prime(t): t \in \mathbf{Z}_{2n}\}$ is a permutation of $\mathbf{Z}_{2n}$, where $\sigma$ and $\sigma^\prime$ are two permutations. Then in particular
$$
n\equiv n(2n+1)=\sum_{i=1}^{2n} i \equiv \sum_{i=1}^{2n} \sigma(i)+\sigma^\prime(i)=2\sum_{i=1}^{2n} i\equiv 0\pmod{2n}.
$$
Hence it has *at least* one repeated element.

However, it is possible that it has *exactly* one repeated element: choose $\mathbf{Z}_{2n}=\mathbf{Z}_4$ and $f(t)=t$ for $t \in \{0,1\}$, $f(2)=3$, and $f(3)=2$.

Comment: But $n\geq 2$ is given in the question!

Comment: You're right, edited

Comment: But it is not correct the  counter you are giving! f(0)-0=0 and f(1)-1=0

Comment: It is the *one* element which is repeating. On the other hand, we have seen that there is *at least* one.

Comment: So, that means that the answer to question is yes right?

Comment: You have actually proved that $g(t)=f(t)-t$ is not a bijection on $\mathbb{Z}_{2n}$ is it?

Comment: $f(t)-t$ is not a bijection, right. So it has at least one repeated element. But not necessarily two.